# Change background color of title using declaretheoremstyle

Tags: theorems, mdframed, thmtools

Here's my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,pdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools,amsthm,amssymb}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[most,many,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{color}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,hooks}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=1em,skipbelow=0em}

\definecolor{example}{HTML}{00A6E4}

\makeatletter
\def\zz{\edef\zzz{\pdfliteral{\current@color}}}
\makeatother

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\zz\color{example}, bodyfont=\normalfont, headpunct=
]{thmexamplebox}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter, style=thmexamplebox, name=EXAMPLE]{example}
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\arabic{example}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{example}
    hi
  \end{example}
\end{document}
```

which creates the following pdf:

[image]

How can I add a background color to the title of the environment like the following?

[image]

Also, what type of font are they using?

If possible, I'd like to use the `declaretheoremstyle` and `declaretheorem` like I have above, since all my other theorems are using it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer!!

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,pdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools,amsthm,amssymb}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[most,many,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{color}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,hooks}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=1em,skipbelow=0em}

\definecolor{example}{HTML}{00A6E4}
\definecolor{examplebg}{HTML}{CAE4F0}

\makeatletter
\def\zz{\edef\zzz{\pdfliteral{\current@color}}}
\makeatother

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries\zz\color{example}\colorbox{examplebg}{EXAMPLE \arabic{example}},
  headformat=\NOTE,
  notefont=\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  notefont=\zzz\bfseries,
  notebraces={~ },
  headpunct=,
]{thmexamplebox}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter, style=thmexamplebox, name=] {example}
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\arabic{example}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{example}[Finding Maclaurin series by multiplication and division]
    Find the first three nonzero terms in the Maclaurin series for (a) $e^{x}$
    and (b) $\tan(x)$.
  \end{example}
\end{document}
```

which creates the following pdf:

[image]