# Is possible to use declaretheoremstyle with newtheorem for modifying theorem style?

Tags: environments, newtheorem

I'm typing some lecture notes I had with some theorems, propositions, axioms, etc., and I want to modify the style for such environments: add macros, shaded backgrounds, or any simple modification ([Change background color of title using declaretheoremstyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666175/change-background-color-of-title-using-declaretheoremstyle)).

I've used this solution before: [Using mdframed style within \declaretheoremstyle to change title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110244/using-mdframed-style-within-declaretheoremstyle-to-change-title). It uses `\declaretheorem` to implement such style, but the template I've now been using uses \newtheorem instead. Here's my attempt, which doesn't work as the style I declared does not apply.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools,thmtools,framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    mdframed={
        backgroundcolor=gray!20, 
            linecolor=gray!30, 
            innertopmargin=6pt,
            innerbottommargin=6pt} 
]{box}

\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{box} 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[2][4]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

So, my question is how to implement the modified style in the `\newtheorem` environment. Any other solution or comment is welcome.

Comment: Welcome! If you like that style, why not use it? It's not clear what you mean by a 'template' but if you mean a preamble which basically loads a bunch of packages for you, you are almost certainly better without it. You haven't mentioned any good reason to use `\newtheorem` rather than `\declaretheorem`.

Comment: I suggest to look at `tcolorbox` instead. With that you just define environments as usual with `\newtheorem` and “adorn” them later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use `tcolorbox` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

% defina a style to be applied for theorem-like environments
\tcbset{
  manuel-theorems/.style={
    sharp corners,
    skin=tile,
    colback=gray!20,
  },
}

% wrap the desired environments
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_map_inline:nn {theorem,axiom,corollary,lemma,proposition}
 {
  \tcolorboxenvironment{#1}{manuel-theorems}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[2][4]
\end{theorem}

\begin{proposition}
\lipsum[2][4]
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used a mapping over a list rather than a long series of declarations such as

```
\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{manuel-theorems}
```

for each environment.

Comment: Thank you so much! Great answer, exactly what I was looking for